# How to get mysql result in following format

Tags: mysql

Database Tables:
The below tables contain the information about users and their licenses.

Note: One user can have multiple licenses.
[users table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCcrm.png)
Users( 'user_id', 'user_email', 'name' )

[license table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQj3H.png)
Licenses( 'license_id', 'user_id', 'license_key', 'license_status' )

Write an optimized MySql query to generate the output like

[Desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bW2t.png)

Edit:

I have tried this `SELECT u.user_email, u.name as user_name, l.license_status as status, l.license_key FROM users u left join licenses l on u.user_id = l.user_id` but it's not showing expected result and I'm not sure how can I get the [Desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bW2t.png)

Comment: what you have tried, you could show a minimum example

Comment: I have tried this 

SELECT u.user_email, u.name as user_name, l.license_status as status, l.license_key FROM users u left join licenses l on u.user_id = l.user_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GROUP_CONCAT` to the rescue:

```
SELECT  u.user_email,
        u.name as user_name,
        GROUP_CONCAT(l.license_status ORDER BY license_id) AS statuses,
        GROUP_CONCAT(l.license_key ORDER BY license_id) AS "keys"
    FROM  users u
    left join  licenses l  ON u.user_id = l.user_id
    GROUP BY u.user_id
```

If desired change to

```
   COALESCE(GROUP_CONCAT(...), "none") AS ...
```

If you don't want the users with no licenses, change `LEFT JOIN` to `JOIN`.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. it working well except it's not showing users with no licenses.

Comment: @imran - You still have "LEFT" in the query?

Comment: Yes I do have @rick

Comment: @imran - Sorry, I forgot the GROUP BY; see my edit.